# Remove all files within directory older than the most recently added ten files

Tags: command-line, scripts, delete

I have a compressed (tar), backup file which is added to a directory periodically. The files that are added have a naming convention like so:

```
JenkinsBackup_$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).tar.gz
```

Which results in files named like:

```
jenkinsBackup_20170630-091543.tar.gz
```

My goal is to select all files within the directory older than the most recent ten files added to the directory, and delete those files. Essentially a cleanup of the directory from command line.

Can anybody help me with the terminal commands needed to accomplish this? I'm not sure how to select and remove all files within a directory older than the most recent ten files.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: logrotate may already do what you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way that works fine with your file names is to use:

```
ls -t1 | tail -n +11 | xargs gvfs-rm
```

- `ls -t1` gives us a list of files based on their modification time, and newest files are first.
- using `tail -n +11` we are skipping first 10 line and getting everything else
- then we pipe the list to `xargs gvfs-rm` for removal.

Note that `gvfs-rm` moves the file to the trash, use `rm` to permanently remove them.

If you want to work with the file names instead of their modification time then use `ls -1r | tail -n +11 | xargs gvfs-rm` instead.

A similar `find` solution that decides based on file names:

```
find -type f | sort -r | tail -n +11 | xargs gvfs-rm
```

or

```
find -type f | sort | head -n -10 | xargs gvfs-rm
```

Comment: It looks like this may keep the oldest ten, and removing anything newer than the oldest ten files. I am trying to keep the newest ten, and remove anything older than the ten newest files. Thank for for the advice though so far very helpful!

Comment: Yes i tested the command listed above in terminal and I see my most recent file (the 11th), removed from the directory. In this case, the 1st file of the 11 should be removed.

Comment: I updated the answer ;)

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thanks you saved my ass this morning :D Just wondering if you have the time to update the description of the command executed in your answer above? I'd like to know exactly why this works!

Comment: Updated again and you're welcome...

Comment: Your the best! Thank you very much for your effort!

Answer (score 2):

#### Python

I assume the directory contains **only** your backups. If it has other files, the wrong files will get deleted.

```
import os
for f in sorted(os.listdir('.'))[:-10]:
    os.remove(f)
```

#### Explanation

- `os.listdir('.')` gets filenames in the current directory
- `sorted()` sorts the filenames in ascending order (oldest first)
- `[:-10]` selects the whole list except the last ten items
- `os.remove()` deletes each file

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to `zsh` it's much easier than jumping though hoops with `ls`, `find` or `stat`. For example, given

```
 % ls -1 JenkinsBackup_*
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095544.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095545.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095546.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095547.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095548.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095549.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095550.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095551.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095552.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095553.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095554.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095555.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095556.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095557.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095558.tar.gz
```

List by modification time, newest first using the `om` (**o**rder by **m**odification time) glob qualifier:

```
 % printf '%s\n' JenkinsBackup_*(om)
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095558.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095557.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095556.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095555.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095554.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095553.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095552.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095551.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095550.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095549.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095548.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095547.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095546.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095545.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095544.tar.gz
```

List by modification time, newest first, and select from the 11th up:

```
 % printf '%s\n' JenkinsBackup_*(om[11,-1])
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095548.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095547.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095546.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095545.tar.gz
JenkinsBackup_20170630-095544.tar.gz
```

Delete matching files older than the 10th newest:

```
 % rm -v JenkinsBackup_*(om[11,-1])
removed 'JenkinsBackup_20170630-095548.tar.gz'
removed 'JenkinsBackup_20170630-095547.tar.gz'
removed 'JenkinsBackup_20170630-095546.tar.gz'
removed 'JenkinsBackup_20170630-095545.tar.gz'
removed 'JenkinsBackup_20170630-095544.tar.gz'
```

See [zsh: 14 Expansion: Filename Generation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation)