# how to delete all but X last items from find

Tags: command-line, find, ls

I want to find some dirs and delete all but the 10 latest dirs.

I can `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "XXX*" | xargs rm -rf` but that would remove all of them.

I can't use `head / tail` because I don't know the length of the list. I thought of piping the result to `wc -l` and then doing subtracting 10 from it and then `rm -rf`'ing it, but I don't know how...

What I came up till now is this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "XXX*" | # get the dirs list
wc -l | # count number
xargs -I{} expr {} - $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "XXX*") # send number to xargs and try to use expr to subtract from it the tail of the find
```

I'm stuck in the `expr` part and how to cut the list where I want

Comment: oh my... I see I was way too creative. Thx!!

Comment: Related: [Remove all files within directory older than the most recently added ten files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930694/remove-all-files-within-directory-older-than-the-most-recently-added-ten-files)

Answer (score 4):

Here you are:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "XXX*" -print0 | head -zn-10 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

I have tested it, working fine. Note current directory `"."` also counts if `-name "*"`

From [`man head`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/head.1.html):

> -n, --lines=[-]NUM
>             print the first NUM lines instead of  the  first  10;  with  the
>             leading '-', print all but the last NUM lines of each file