# How to delete all but X last created files ordered by name?

Tags: command-line, filesystem

I have a directory with database backups stored in `data-atm1-YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.sql.gz` filename format.

Q: How do I delete all files but I need to keep last X files? (ordered in descendant order by filename).

Comment: Related: [Remove all files within directory older than the most recently added ten files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930694/remove-all-files-within-directory-older-than-the-most-recently-added-ten-files)

Comment: @bac0n do what manually? if you are referring to the linked question, my zsh answer could be modified to use lexical name order as `*(On[11,-1])` (although probably mtime would also work here - unless the names of the backups do not correspond to their true dates)

Comment: @bac0n doh! yes, in that sense I "did it manually" - I just wasn't sure it counted as an exact dupe (since the ordering criterion is - at least nominally - different)